# Pandas Dataframe - find max between two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
Students | Math | Reading
Tom | 80 | 75
Mike | 65 | 90
```

I want to import this csv and determine which `Student` has the largest difference between their `Math` and `Reading` scores.

In this example.  I expect `Mike` to be the result as his difference is `25` while Tom's difference is `15`.

Comment: Create a column that is the difference and then `abs().max()` that column.

Answer (score 4):

You want `Student` to be the index of the dataframe.  With the sample data you gave, I'd import it like this.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\s*\|\s*', engine='python', index_col=0)
```

This will separate the columns when it sees zero or more spaces followed by a vertical bar followed by zero or more spaces.  It will also se the index to be the `Students` column

Now you can use this to find the `Student` with the largest absolute difference between their respective `Math` and `Reading` scores.

```
df.Math.sub(df.Reading).abs().idxmax()

'Mike'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So if I have a dataframe read from csv file which has multiple rows and columns. Each row is one student and there are two columns like math and reading score. How do I find the students which has biggest difference between math and reading? I tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: @art I gave you an example that does work. When you ask a question with so little detail, you assume the responsibility of adapting my suggestion to your situation. If you have trouble doing that, then make it easy on me and edit your question with example data. Show me what you think the output should look like. Things could not work from as little as 'math' not being upper case. How would I know unless you tell me the specifics

Comment: Thanks for your help piRSquared. I am very new on both Pandas and this site. So if I have a list like this. Students | Math | Reading on first row; Tom | 80 | 75 on 2nd row; Mike | 65 | 90 on 3rd row....                                                                                                                                                  What's the best way to find out which students has the biggest difference between Math and Reading score?  I tried this and it doesn't work                              df(df['Math']-df['Reading']).argmax()

Comment: @art I've updated my post as well as yours.  Note how I edited your question to present the relevant information.  I'd even suggest clicking the edit button to see what syntax I used to highlight certain things.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am certainly learned a lot from this post. :)